# How to know Bios drive no. for 3rd master SATA hard disk?

Tags: assembly, sata

Uptill now I was using IDE hard disk and was able to access using BIOS calls and even LBA 28 direct hardware aceess usng PIO mode without need of any O.S. call.
Now I have purchased new SATA 500 GB hard disk and it is my only hard disk attached to SATA 1 port. My BIOS is showing it as 3rd Master Hard disk and primary and secondary master are absent.
Now I have installed MS DOS 5.0 on first partition which runs okay.
But now I can use only DOS INT 25h TO READ HARD DISK sectors starting from logical sector 0. This means I can not read any hidden sectors including Master Boot Record.
When I use BIOS int 13H calls to read hard disk  using drive 80H it does not return any error, but reads nothing. If I use drive 83H it gives drive does not exists error. If I use DOS functions I can access my HDD as drive c ( drive 2) But can not be use to read MBR.
If I shall use MS extension for int 13H I must know the BIOS drive no.
Can anybody tells me how to find drive no. of 3rd Master Harddisk ? 
Or which Port I have to use to access HDD using LBA 40 ( 01f0 does not work) in compatibilty mode ?

Answer (score 0):

[Ralf Brown's Interrupt List](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/id/28/41.html) recommends hooking INT 13h and invoking INT 25h to see what BIOS drive number MS-DOS uses:

> A method to detect the actual assignments of logical drive numbers
>      to physical BIOS drive units (for example to detect the boot drive),
>      is to temporarily mount an INT 13h handler recording the used DL
>      drive unit for any INT 13/AH=02h read operations and discarding any
>      attempts to access actual floppy drives.  Then call INT 25h for
>      all the appropriate DOS drives and watch the results recorded by
>      the INT 13h interceptor.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I have found that my physical drive is shown as 80H only, My program was reading sectors no. 0 instead of sector no. 1 That was silly mistake.